# tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add function did work

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

I want to insert two slices in the first Dimension of a tensor with two matrices of new values, I am using the method `tensor_scatter_add` but it gives me an error

```
indices = tf.constant([[0], [2]])
updates = tf.constant([[[5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6],
                        [7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8]],
                       [[5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6],
                        [7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8]]])
tensor = tf.ones([4, 5, 4])
updated = tf.tensor_scatter_add(tensor, indices, updates)
with tf.Session() as se:
  print(ses.run(scatter))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just correct these lines, you are typing it wrongly and this casued the problem in your code:

```
tensor = tf.ones([4, 4, 4])
updated = tf.tensor_scatter_add(tensor, indices, updates)
with tf.Session() as se:
  print(se.run(scatter))
```

Comment: ```se.run(scatter)``` is erroneous because `scatter` isn't defined anywhere. `updated` is what should be passed to `se` or perhaps rename updated to scatter.

Answer (score 2):

The inner 2 dimensions of `tensor` must match the inner 2 dimensions of `updates`. `Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 5 and 4`.

`tensor` must be of the same `dtype` as `updates` but are different in your code.

There are errors in:

```py
with tf.Session() as se:
  print(ses.run(scatter))
```

you alias `tf.Session()` as `se` but call `ses` instead of `se` and your passing scatter to `ses.run()` yet its not defined anywhere; `se.run(updated)` should be the right function call.

**Snippet with code fixes:**

This should work fine for you.

```py
indices = tf.constant([[0], [2]])
updates = tf.constant([[[5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6],
                        [7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8]],
                       [[5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6],
                        [7, 7, 7, 7], [8, 8, 8, 8]]])
tensor = tf.ones([4, 4, 4], dtype=tf.int32)
updated = tf.tensor_scatter_nd_add(tensor, indices, updates)
with tf.Session() as se:
  print(se.run(updated))
```